# Why is my /etc/hosts.deny file being ignored?

Tags: ssh, busybox, hosts, buildroot

I am using a small embedded linux setup generated by `buildroot` to run on a x86 device. It was generated to use `busybox` init system and also runs dropbear so I can ssh into the device.

I wanted to block the `ssh` access so I went to edit the `/etc/hosts.deny' file. It did not exist so I created it with the following content

```
ALL : ALL
```

and rebooted. I expected it to block any attempts to ssh into it but to my surprise I found that I could still do so.

I have tried to find further details about this but I have come to the conclusion that the `buildroot` system is not configured to use this file. My question is about what applications on a linux system actually read the contents of `/etc/hosts.deny` and act upon it. 
I have read the man pages but I cannot find anything that tells me this. Is it possible that this is just incompatible approach to the `buildroot` generated system?? Or is there something wrong with the content of the file?

Comment: `hosts.allow` and `hosts.deny` are used by the TCP wrappers mechanism (services maintained by `inetd` or the equivalent daemon on your system ). `sshd` doesn't use TCP wrappers, so `/etc/hosts.{allow,deny}` don't apply to it.

Comment: Thing is, my comment is flat out wrong. The `sshd` in OpenSSH *does* use TCP wrappers (any process can on a voluntary basis, not just those started by `tcpd`). The manpage says so too. Since this is an embedded system, are you using Dropbear SSH instead of OpenSSH?

Comment: @Alexios Yes I use Dropbear on my system.